# Google Script Email loop

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am relatively new to programming, and have recently been working on a script to send emails from a google spreadsheet when a cell in a certain column is changed. The recipient is assigned based off of an email address in another column in the same row as the change. I am having difficulty getting my code to stop running after the first email. As it is, the script runs indefinitely (at least until I run out of emails for the day).

Here is the code:

```
    function sendNotification() {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Get Active cell
  var mycell = sheet.getActiveSelection();
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  var address = sheet.getRange("C" + cellrow).getValue();
  var streetAddress = sheet.getRange("F" + cellrow).getValue();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = 2000;  
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:O2000
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 15)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = address;  // First column
    var message = streetAddress +" Has been Submitted for permitting!";             // Second column
    var subject = "The above Address has been Submitted For Permitting! We     will Follow up with you when it has been approved.";
  //Check to see if column is H to trigger
      if (cellcol == 8 && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && mycell !== "")
      {
  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, message, subject);
      }
  //End sendNotification
  }
  }
```

What can I do to resolve this? Would a loop be the best option? How would I implement this?

How about this approach?

var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var mycell = e.range;
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("C" + cellrow).getValue();
  var streetAddress = sheet.getRange("F" + cellrow).getValue();
  var subject = "The above Address has been Submitted For Permitting! We     will follow up with you when it has been approved."
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range
    var message = streetAddress +" Has been Submitted for permitting!";  
    var emailSent = sheet.getRange("O" + cellrow).getValue();    
    if ( cellcol == 8 && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && emailSent !=      EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(cellrow, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is     interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your loop runs 2000 times, since you're fetching 2000 rows. The IF control on **line 22** should check that value on current row and column 8 (H) is not empty `row[8] != ""`. Instead you're checking `mycell != ""` that references a cell outside the loop. Also `cellcol == 8` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: The thing is, I only want to send the email if the edited cell is in column 8. I think I was approaching this all wrong. Does this look any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `onEdit()` the function will be triggered every time you edit the cell. Is this what you want? 
What I assume you're looking for is a script that:

1. Reads every row of the active sheet
2. If the 8th column is not empty, sends an e-mail to the address in the first column
3. The whole script is trigger upon the user requests (not when the user edits a cell)

In this case the first approach is better, the `sendNotification()`. Also a loop is necessary to read all the rows. And the IF statement should be something like `if (row[8] != "")` then send the e-mail.

In this case `row` which was defined as `row = data[i]` in your first script will have the values of all the cells in the row being read in the loop. So `row[8]` will have the value of the 8th (column H), which you want to check for emptiness, thus `if(row[8] != "")`.

Also, if I understand correctly the e-mail adress should be `emailAddress = row[1]` inside the loop, because the email address is different every row.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach `var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";` is almost similar to the simple extension of the code that sets the cells in a column to 'EMAIL_SENT' for each row after `sendEmail` is called given in [Section 2: Improvements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section-2-improvements). Within tutorial, each cell was marked in each row every time an email is sent. With that, you should mark edited cells as unsent then you will be able to re-run the script later on, avoid sending email duplicates and will only send the edited cells.

To make your code more efficient and help you improve the performance of your scripts, there are also list of [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#top_of_page) given.